# Upgrading to Symfony 6 from 5.3

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I updated my composer.json file to reflect the 6.0.* changes, and ran my `composer update "symfony/*"` code, and it returned this:

```
    Problem 1
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle is locked to version 2.4.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.4.3 requires symfony/config ^4.4.3|^5.0|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.3, ..., 4.4.x-dev, v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev, v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.1.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle is locked to version v5.6.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle v5.6.1 requires symfony/config ^4.4|^5.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev, v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/security-http 6.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/security-http[v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.0.x-dev].
    - symfony/security-http[v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.0.x-dev] require symfony/http-kernel ^5.4|^6.0 -> found symfony/http-kernel[v5.4.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev, v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.1.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 4
    - symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle is locked to version v1.10.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle v1.10.0 requires symfony/config ^4.4 | ^5.0 | ^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev, v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev, v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.1.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 5
    - symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle is locked to version v1.6.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle v1.6.0 requires symfony/config ^4.4 | ^5.0 | ^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev, v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev, v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.1.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 6
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle is locked to version 3.4.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.4.1 requires symfony/config ^3.4|^4.3|^5.0|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v3.4.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev, v4.3.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev, v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev, v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.1.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 7
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.4.3 requires symfony/config ^4.4.3|^5.0|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.3, ..., 4.4.x-dev, v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev, v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.1.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 3.2.1 requires doctrine/doctrine-bundle ~1.0|~2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.4.3].
    - doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle is locked to version 3.2.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Some of these notifications confuse me because I'm not sure what to do when a package is locked a version.

Here is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.1",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.8",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.76",
        "symfony/asset": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.7",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/postmark-mailer": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/rate-limiter": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/security-core": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/security-guard": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/security-http": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/string": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/validator": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.11",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.0.*",
        "symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle": "^1.3",
        "taxjar/taxjar-php": "^1.10",
        "twig/cssinliner-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^3.3",
        "twig/inky-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/intl-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^5.3",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^5.3",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.3",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.3",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.0.*"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I resolve these problems and also what can I do moving forward so I can be more aware of how to fix these on my own?

Comment: For me the easiest approach is to create a new 6.0 project, add your stripe package and then use the resulting composer.json file.  At the very least you can compare it to what you have.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Did you try to also upgrade the remaining packages from Symfony 5.3, and not just a fraction of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That composer.json file is a bit of a mess. Some Symfony packages on 5.3, some even on 5.1, and many on 6.

Also you are controlling Symfony versioning from `extra.symfony.require`, and at the same time from the discrete version constraints. You include some packages that no longer exist on 6.0 (`symfony/security-guard`), and are missing some that *should* be installed on a 6.0 version.

It's simply not on an installable state.

I've managed to make it installable changing it like this:

```json
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.1",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.8",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.0.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.76",
        "symfony/asset": "*",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "v2.1.4",
        "symfony/form": "*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/http-client": "*",
        "symfony/intl": "*",
        "symfony/mailer": "*",
        "symfony/mime": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.7",
        "symfony/notifier": "*",
        "symfony/postmark-mailer": "*",
        "symfony/process": "*",
        "symfony/property-access": "*",
        "symfony/property-info": "*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "*",
        "symfony/rate-limiter": "*",
        "symfony/runtime": "*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/security-core": "*",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "*",
        "symfony/security-http": "*",
        "symfony/serializer": "*",
        "symfony/string": "*",
        "symfony/translation": "*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/validator": "*",
        "symfony/web-link": "*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.11",
        "symfony/yaml": "*",
        "symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle": "^1.3",
        "taxjar/taxjar-php": "^1.10",
        "twig/cssinliner-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^3.3",
        "twig/inky-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/intl-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "*",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": false,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.0.*",
            "docker": true
        }
    }
}
```

Since this will not match your locked versions, I would simply delete your `vendor` directory and your `composer.lock` and run `composer install`. You'll have to deal with all the different changes from the new recipes, but hopefully this is version-controlled project so it's a matter of going through the changes and see where what issues arise.

It's going to be fun.

Comment: I did what was suggested, then I got this error: `Typed property Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route::$env must not be accessed before initialization`

Comment: With the above `composer.json`, on an empty directory, I’m able to run `composer install` and `bin/console cache:clear` successfully. If you got other errors, it means they come from somewhere else, that’s not present in the question. Right now, you don’t even mention when exactly you get this error.

Comment: My advice would be to use the above configuration on an empty directory, install everything, and then copy your code bit by bit solving the issues as they arise.